# jasmine testing uncaught error event handler

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I am having difficulties testing a new package that I am writing with jasmine. 
The [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/all-error-handler) idea is to create a listener for error or "uncaughtException" (in node) and give it a callback to work if there is such event.

```
describe('AllErrorHandler', function () {
    it('error is passed to the callback', function () {
        const error = new Error("testError");
        const callbackError;

        let errorHandler = new AllErrorHandler((error) => {
            callbackError = error;
        })

        throw error;

        expect(callbackError).toBe(error);
    })
})
```

How can I make this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `error` is not a function. You need `throw error` not `throw error()`.

Then the line after you throw is not reachable (unless you wrap the whole thing with try-catch :) which kinda beats the whole point of the test).

You could try something like this. But I'm not 100% this would work.

```
describe('AllErrorHandler', function () {
    it('error is passed to the callback', function (done) {
        const error = new Error("testError");

        let errorHandler = new AllErrorHandler((arg1) => {
           expect(arg1).toBe(error);
           done();
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
          throw error;
        }, 0)
    })
})
```

Comment: yea about the error it was a typo while writing the example. I am going to fix it.

Comment: It works, thanks! And about the setTimeout function could you give me an explanation how this works.

Comment: You want to throw an error but also you need current function to finish its execution w/o exception. So you need to create another function and call it later using `setTimeout` or `setImmediate`.